# JQuery 'fadeIn' firing too soon, before the images are done loading

Tags: jquery, transition, fadein, fadeout

I'm putting the final touch to my friend's portfolio website (using wordpress) but I'm having an issue with a simple JQuery page transition fadeIn effect.

Here's the link to the site: **(warning: NSFW)** http://www.alexdebrabant.com/front/

In the "PROJECTS" section, I'm using a the Jquery cycle to create a slideshow with all the pictures in the post. It's working great.
But in the "PORTRAITS" section, the situation is a bit different as I only have one picture per post. Therefore, the PREV NEXT buttons takes the visitor to a new post, hence a new page has to load every time.
My idea was to try to mimic the slideshow from the "PROJECTS" section using some sort of fade transition.
At the moment, I only have a very basic fadeIn effect.
My problem is that, unless the images are cached, the fadeIn effect fires too soon, before the image is done loading.

I'm a newbie with JQuery and I suspect there must be an easy solution but I can't seem to find it.

Also, if any of you know of a Jquery effect that would better mimic / replicate the slideshow from the "PROJECTS" section, that would also be great. Perhaps a page cross fade effect (if that exists) or a fade out / fade in maybe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<!-- contentload -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#content').fadeIn(500);

});
</script>
<!-- contentload -->

<style>
#content {display: none;}
</style>
```

Cheers!

Thom

Comment: That link contains explicit content! =/ -1 for no warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$(window).load()` or `$('img').load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`. The whole *point* of `document.ready` is that it fires when the DOM is ready for querying, *not* when the entire page has loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot MДΓΓ БДLL! I knew there must be a simple to solution. I just changed it and works perfectly. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead of `document.ready`